# How can I initialize a property of my state from another state?

Tags: redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

In my web app, I am trying to create the functionality for multiple items to be transferred from one state to another. I am trying to move items from a shopping cart to a pantry array. When adding items to the pantry, I want to be able to update the quantity of that item in the pantry according to how many of that item was just purchased, ie. the quantity of the item in the cart. How might I go about this?

pantrySlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const pantrySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'pantry',
    initialState: {
        pantry: [],

    },
    reducers: {
        addToPantry: (state, action) => {
            const itemInPantry = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);

            if (itemInPantry) {
                itemInPantry.quantity += 1;
            } else {
                state.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
                
            }
        },
        incrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
            const item = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
            if (!item) return;
            item.quantity++;
        },
        decrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
            const item = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
            if (!item) { return}
            if (item.quantity === 1) {
                item.quantity = 1
            } else {
                item.quantity--;
            }
        },
        removeItem: (state, action) => {
            return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
        },
    }
});

export const { addToPantry, incrementQuantity, decrementQuantity, removeItem } = pantrySlice.actions;
export const selectPantry = (state) => state.pantry;
export const pantryReducer = pantrySlice.reducer;
```

cartSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState: {
        cart: [],
        total: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        addToCart: (state, action) => {
          const itemInCart = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
          if (itemInCart) {
            itemInCart.quantity++;
          } else {
            state.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
          }
        },
        incrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
          const item = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
          if (!item) return;
          item.quantity++;
        },
        decrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
          const item = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
          if (!item) { return}
          if (item.quantity === 1) {
            item.quantity = 1
          } else {
            item.quantity--;
          }
        },
        removeItem: (state, action) => {
          return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
        },
      },
})

export const { addToCart, incrementQuantity, decrementQuantity, removeItem } = cartSlice.actions;
export const selectCart = (state) => state.cart;
export const cartReducer = cartSlice.reducer;
```